# Is this representation of a Lie algebra decomposable?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed characteristic zero field, consider the $\mathfrak{gl}_{1}$ representation

$$
\rho: \mathfrak{gl}_{1} \rightarrow k^{2}
$$

given by

$$
\rho(x) = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & x \\\ 0 & \beta \end{pmatrix}
$$

Then this has a subrepresentation

$$
\\{ \begin{pmatrix} a \\\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : a \in k \\}
$$

where $\rho(x)$ just acts as a scalar $\alpha$, so this subrep is isomorphic to $k_{\alpha}$

The quotient representation also just acts as a scalar $\beta$.

So $\alpha, \beta$ are the weights of $k^{2}$ (since $k_{\alpha}, k_{\beta}$ are the composition factors of $k^{2}$.)

I know that a representation of a nilpotent Lie algebra decomposes as the direct sum of its weight spaces. (Also, the weight spaces are equal to the generalised eigenspaces of $\rho(x)$ for a generic element $x \in \mathfrak{gl}_{1}$.)

$\mathfrak{gl}_{1}$ is nilpotent, so for $\alpha \ne \beta$, I am trying to decompose $k^{2}$ as

$$
k^{2} = k_{\alpha} \oplus k_{\beta}
$$

But I cannot see what $k_{\beta}$ should be as a subrepresentation of $k^{2}$?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: How is $\rho$ a representation? If $x,y\in\mathfrak{gl}_1$, then $\rho([x,y])=\rho(0)=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&0\\0&\beta\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, whereas\begin{align}\bigl[\rho(x),\rho(y)\bigr]&=\rho(x)\rho(y)-\rho(y)\rho(x)\\&=\begin{bmatrix}0&(\beta-\alpha)(x-y)\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\end{align}which, in general, is not $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}\alpha&0\\0&\beta\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: Ah, that's why it's not working! Thank you :)